# What do the rune numbers mean?

Tags: guild-wars-2

[image]

```
Some gear has these numbers. It says Minor Rune of xxx (0/2)
(1) Does something.
(2) Does something better.
```

Does this mean this item has a rune? If so, does it mean you need to have two of those runes on this piece of gear to get the second effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(0/2)` means that you have 0 out of a possible 2 of these runes equipped. When you have 1 of these runes equipped you will get the bonus listed under `(1)`, and when you have 2 equipped you will get the bonus listed under `(2)` as well.

For instance, from your screenshot you have an item that has a `Minor Rune of Hoelbrak` in it. If you were to equip it, you would get an extra 10 power because you now have one of this rune equipped. If you were to then equip a pair of boots with another of these runes in it you will get an extra 10% Might Duration for equipping those boots.

Comment: So if you have two runes, do you get both effects?  Or just `(2)`?

Comment: Both effects. It's similar to a "set" rune

Comment: So is this to encourage people to double up on runes? Do all runes have (2) affixes or do some have more/less?

Comment: @Emerica.: You can do what you like with them. I believe there are some that have more than 2 (up to 6), but I don't think I've seen any with just 1. In fact, I've heard people recommend not going all the way to 6 with some runes. It just depends what the bonuses are and what you actually need.

Comment: @Emerica.: I stand corrected. I've just picked up a sigil without any set bonus, so they do exist also.